# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Tags: objective-c, ios6.1

It gives error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)
My code:

```
@synthesize s1;
@synthesize s2;
@synthesize s3;
@synthesize s4;
@synthesize s5;
@synthesize s6;
@synthesize s7;
@synthesize s8;
@synthesize s9;
@synthesize oImg,xImg,theImg,whoseTurn,board;
@synthesize resetButton, myAlertView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initalization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    oImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"O copy.jpg"];
    xImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"X copy.jpg"];

    playerToken = 1;

    whoseTurn.text = @"X can go";

    numberOfPlays = 0;


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    switch(playerToken){
        case 1:theImg = xImg;
            break;
        case 2:
            theImg = oImg;
            break;
    }

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    cellWasUsed = NO;

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s1 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s1.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s1.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s2 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s2.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s2.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s3 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s3.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s3.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s4 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s4.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s4.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s5 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s5.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s5.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s6 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s6.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s6.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s7 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s7.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s7.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s8 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s8.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s8.image = theImg;
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([s9 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])&(s9.image == NULL)) {
        cellWasUsed = YES;
        s9.image = theImg;
    }
    [self processLogic];
    if (cellWasUsed) {
        [self updatePlayerInfo];
    }
}

-(void)processLogic{

    if ([self checkForWin]){
        if(playerToken ==1){
            myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"winner" message:@"X won" delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [myAlertView show];
            [self resetBoard];
        }
        else if(playerToken ==2){
            myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"winner" message:@"O won" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [myAlertView show];
            [self resetBoard];
        }
        if(numberOfPlays ==9){
            myAlertView = [[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Winner" message:@"Tie" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [myAlertView show];

            [self resetBoard];
        }



    }

}

-(BOOL)checkForWin{

    // HORIZONTAL WINS
    if((s1.image == s2.image) & (s2.image == s3.image) & (s1.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if((s4.image == s5.image) & (s5.image == s6.image) & (s4.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if((s7.image == s8.image) & (s8.image == s9.image) & (s7.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    // VERTICAL WINS
    if((s1.image == s4.image) & (s4.image == s7.image) & (s1.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if((s2.image == s5.image) & (s5.image == s8.image) & (s2.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if((s3.image == s6.image) & (s6.image == s9.image) & (s3.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    // DIAGONAL WINS
    if((s1.image == s5.image) & (s5.image == s9.image) & (s1.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if((s3.image == s5.image) & (s5.image == s7.image) & (s3.image != NULL))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    //right now return 1 becuase we havn't implemented this yet
    return NO;
}

-(void)displayWinner{
    if([self checkForWin]==YES){
        if(playerToken ==1){
            whoseTurn.text =@"X is the winner!";

        }
        else{whoseTurn.text = @"O is the winner!";

        }
    }

}

-(IBAction)buttonReset{

    [self resetBoard];

}

-(void)resetBoard{

    s1.image =NULL;
    s2.image =NULL;
    s3.image =NULL;
    s4.image =NULL;
    s5.image =NULL;
    s6.image =NULL;
    s7.image =NULL;
    s8.image =NULL;
    s9.image =NULL;

    playerToken =1;
    whoseTurn.text = @"X can go";

    numberOfPlays = 0;






}

-(void)updatePlayerInfo{
    numberOfPlays++;
    if(numberOfPlays ==9){

        [self resetBoard];
    }
    if (playerToken ==1){

        playerToken =2;
        whoseTurn.text = @"O can go";

    } else {
        playerToken = 1;
        whoseTurn.text = @"X can go";
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [s1 release];
    [s2 release];
    [s3 release];
    [s4 release];
    [s5 release];
    [s6 release];
    [s7 release];
    [s8 release];
    [s9 release];
    [theImg release];
    [resetButton release];
    [board release];
    [oImg release];
    [xImg release];
    [whoseTurn release];
    [myAlertView release];



    [super dealloc];


}


@end `
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Instead of single &:

    if((s3.image == s5.image) & (s5.image == s7.image) & (s3.image != NULL))

Use double &&:

    if((s3.image == s5.image) && (s5.image == s7.image) && (s3.image != NULL))

Comment: You can't post a bunch of code and say "what's wrong?". At least provide more details about the full error message and point out where in your code (based on the stack trace) it is crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using `[super dealloc]` I guess your project is non-ARC. In that case, when you create `xImg` and `oImg` with `-imageNamed` you do not retain them (and in `-dealloc` you do release them. Maybe, you should read more properly about memory management in iOS?). So in `-touchBegan` you are accessing deallocated objects, which cause error. Use instead

```
oImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"O copy.jpg"] retain];
```

You can also convert your project to ARC by Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to ARC.

Also I highly recommend to use buttons to catch the touches, try to avoid copy-pasting code, and, as NSElvis mentioned, use && instead of &